# Bug with my relation HasMany/BelongsTo

Tags: sql, laravel

I have a model Work with this relation

```
public function types()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Type');
}
```

And a model Type with this relation

```
public function works()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Work');
}
```

I try to access in my view show view to type but I've a lot of errors

`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name`

I try this : `$work->types()->name` for get data.

In my DB, my table 'Works' have a foreignkey 'type_id'.

I would like to get the 'type' of the post. There can be only one per post.

Thank you very much !

Comment: `$work->types()->get()->name` (or possibly `$work->types()->first()->name`) or perhaps `$work->types->name`

Comment: Try: `$work->types->name` (without the braces "()"). in addition to that: your class `Work` has just one type so you should make the name singular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semantically you want to make your relationships like so:

**Work**

```
// A work is of a single type
public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Type');
}
```

**Type**

```
// A type of work can have many items of work
public function works()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Work');
}
```

You can then access the relationship like so:

```
$type = Work::first()->type // return object of type Type
$works = Type::first()->works // return collection of objects of type Work
```

**EDIT**

By accessing the relationship with `()` you are returning the underlying query builder instance of the relationship and you will need to finish your statement with `->get()` like so:

`$works = Type::first()->works()->get();`

Answer (score 2):

You should have on Work Model:

```
public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Type');
}
```

and on your view:

```
$work->type->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using default id as foreign key you should add

```
protected $primaryKey = "type_id";
```

in your model