# How to access parent attributes with a relation of belongsTo and hasMany within the same class?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I'm working with Laravel 8, so far I have two models that I want to relate

```
Role[1]---[n]Users


class Role extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function users(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class,'user_id_fk5');
    }
}
```

and the Users looks like this

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'rol_id',
    ];

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'rol_id_fk4');
    }

    public function hasRole($role): bool
    {
        Log::info('Checking role ' . $role->role()->first()->get());
        Log::info('Current User rolId ' . $this->rol_id);
        Log::info('Current User name ' . $this->name);
        if ($this->role()->where('id', $role)->first()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have read the documentation and it appears that I'm using the correct relationships but I'm not sure how can I query the data from within the same model.

This will result in an exception

```
$role->role()->first()->get()
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983386/bug-with-my-relation-hasmany-belongsto) but they query the data from outside of the model and thus not sure how to access the data from the same instance, any clue?

**Update**

I workarounded the issue with this

```
public function hasRole(string $roleName): bool
{
    $role = Role::where('id', $this->rol_id)->first();
    if ($role->name == $roleName) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

at this point, I don't understand what we gain by adding the belongsTo

Comment: I think you want to get this because in your code you just tried to get the role from the role but you want to get users from role
$role->users()->get()

Answer (score 0):

Get user

```
$user = User::first();
```

After that summoned the relationship and access a property that you want

```
$user->role->name
```

Comment: $role is a string variable, the main issue is that I want to access a property that is part of the Role(id, name) from the User(id, name, role_id), according to what I have read it should be through $this->role() but I'm not sure how to access the value from the 'belongsTo' object

Comment: OK than get the user

$user = User::first();

after that summoned the relationship and access a property that you wanr

$user->role->name